# refreshing RandomElement() in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode12

I have a list of Colors that I want to refresh using a button. this is what I have right now.

```
var body: some View {
        
        let happy = ["red","blue","purple","green"]
        let randomHappy = happy.randomElement()!
        
        ZStack {
            
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack{
            
            Text(randomHappy)
            
            Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, label: {
                Text("Button")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            })
            }
                
        }
        
    }
}
```

I considered refreshing the whole page, but I think that might be too excessive just to refresh the result of a random element. does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@State` to store a random element from the array.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    static let happy = ["red","blue","purple","green"]

    @State var randomHappy = Self.happy.randomElement()!
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack{
                
                Text(randomHappy)
                
                Button(action: {
                    randomHappy = Self.happy.randomElement()!
                }) {
                    Text("Button")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Under almost all normal circumstances, I wouldn't recommend force unwrapping with `!`, but in this situation, you can guarantee that you'll always get an element back, so it seems reasonable.